# R How to Pass a function as a String Inside another Function

Tags: r, tidyverse, symbols, tidyeval, tidyquant

Any assistance on this little conundrum would be mightily appreciated thanks.

I am trying to pass an argument to the `tq_transmute` function from the `tidyquant` package; the value for the argument is a function, however I would like to pass it as a string (out with the scope of the example below I’ll be passing it via a Shiny `selectInput`).

I have tried every way I can think of to turn the string 'apply.quarterly' into the object `apply.quarterly` accepted by the `mutate_fun` argument. The commented lines are my failed attempts.

Ultimately, I would like to extend this concept to the other arguments also i.e. `FUN = max` to `FUN = ‘max’`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyquant)
library(rlang)

FANG %>%
  group_by(symbol) %>%
  tq_transmute(select     = adjusted, 
               mutate_fun = apply.quarterly,
               # mutate_fun = sym('apply.quarterly'),
               # mutate_fun = syms('apply.quarterly'),
               # mutate_fun = !!sym('apply.quarterly'),
               # mutate_fun = !!!sym('apply.quarterly'),
               # mutate_fun = eval(parse('apply.quarterly')),
               # mutate_fun = eval(substitute('apply.quarterly')),
               # mutate_fun = enquo('apply.quarterly'),
               # mutate_fun = expr(!!enquo('apply.quarterly')),
               # mutate_fun = quo('apply.quarterly'),
               # mutate_fun = enquos('apply.quarterly'),
               # mutate_fun = enquote('apply.quarterly'),
               # mutate_fun = quote('apply.quarterly'),
               # mutate_fun = substitute('apply.quarterly'),
               # mutate_fun = parse('apply.quarterly'),
               # mutate_fun = parse('apply.quarterly'),
               # mutate_fun = ensym('apply.quarterly'),
               # mutate_fun = rlang::as_function('apply.quarterly'),
               # mutate_fun = rlang::as_closure('apply.quarterly'),
               # mutate_fun = rlang::as_quosure('apply.quarterly'),
               # mutate_fun = rlang::as_quosure('apply.quarterly'),
               # mutate_fun = enexpr('apply.quarterly'),
               # mutate_fun = enexprs('apply.quarterly'),
               # mutate_fun = ensym('apply.quarterly'),
               # mutate_fun = ensyms('apply.quarterly'),
               # mutate_fun = eval_tidy('apply.quarterly'),
               # mutate_fun = exprs('apply.quarterly'),
               # mutate_fun = expr_deparse('apply.quarterly'),
               # mutate_fun = expr_label('apply.quarterly'),
               # mutate_fun = expr_label(substitute('apply.quarterly')),
               # mutate_fun = expr_label(quote('apply.quarterly')),
               # mutate_fun = parse_expr('apply.quarterly'),
               # mutate_fun = quasiquotation('apply.quarterly'),
               # mutate_fun = quotation('apply.quarterly'),
               # mutate_fun = quotation('apply.quarterly'),
               FUN        = max, 
               col_rename = "max.close")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that function is a bit finicky for some reason. One way would be to change the call and then evaulate that. For example

```
myfun <- "apply.quarterly"
bquote(FANG %>%
  group_by(symbol) %>%
  tq_transmute(select     = adjusted, 
               mutate_fun = .(as.name(myfun)),
               FUN        = max, 
               col_rename = "max.close")) %>% 
  eval()
```

or if you prefer rlang syntax

```
myfun <- "apply.quarterly"
quo(FANG %>%
         group_by(symbol) %>%
         tq_transmute(select     = adjusted, 
                      mutate_fun = !!sym(myfun),
                      FUN        = max, 
                      col_rename = "max.close")) %>% 
  eval_tidy()
```

Note that we have to treat the entire expression as `rlang` quosure. Unless the `tq_transmute` function was specifically written to handle rlang features like `!!` then they won't work by default.

Comment: the ````bquote```` method works a treat, thanks so much.

Comment: I recommend using `blast <- function(expr, env = caller_env()) eval_bare(enexpr(expr, env))` instead of `quo` + `eval_tidy`. The latter solution always evaluates in a mask even when there is no data. With `blast()`, you can use quasiquotation with immediate evaluation, e.g. `blast(foo(!!x))`.

Comment: Or equivalently, `expr()` + `eval()`, mirroring the `bquote()` + `eval()` solution. There is no reason to use `quo()` and `eval_tidy()` here.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @LionelHenry I guess I still have to learn the differences between eval, eval_bare, and eval_tidy. There isn’t a clearer way of just doing this for one step in the pipe chain, right? We will have to wrap the whole chain in blast() (or the equivalent)

Comment: You're correct that QQ can't be enabled with an independent pipe step. There has to be something like bquote that wraps the pipeline. In most cases you can use `eval()` instead of `eval_bare()` actually, so `eval()` is probably the better go-to when you don't need quosure support. There are differences but they are subtle.

Comment: Thnx @Lionel Henry. I’m not sure why but the ````bquote```` route didn’t work on a subsequent (similar) issue. I swapped over to ````blast```` and it’s now all good in the hood.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `blast()` for quasiquotation with immediate evaluation

```r
blast <- function(expr, env = caller_env()) {
  eval_bare(enexpr(expr), env)
}

blast(list(!!!1:3))
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1
#>
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 2
#>
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 3
```

Then

```r
myfun <- "apply.quarterly"

blast(
  FANG %>%
    group_by(symbol) %>%
    tq_transmute(
      select = adjusted,
      mutate_fun = !!sym(myfun),
      FUN = max,
      col_rename = "max.close"
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the function from the string carrying the name of the function with *get*. The following works, for example:

```
s <- get("sum")
s(c(1,2,3))
```

Comment: That returns an error in the example though ''''Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `nested.col`.
x fun = apply_quarterly not a valid option.
i Input `nested.col` is `purrr::map(...)`.
i The error occurred in group 1: symbol = "AMZN".''''

Comment: ````apply_quarterly <-  get('apply.quarterly')    

FANG %>%
  group_by(symbol) %>%
  tq_transmute(select     = adjusted, 
               # mutate_fun = apply.quarterly,
               mutate_fun = apply_quarterly,
               FUN        = max, 
               col_rename = "max.close")````

Comment: Don't forget to pass `mode = "function"` to `get()` in that case. This way it searches for a function up the chain of environments, even when there are objects of the same name on the way.