# difference between enquo() and toString() within a function

Tags: r, dplyr

I am still a bit confused with the use of enquo and toString. In the example below I basically just try to filter a data frame and sum the rows in the end. I don't really understand why is enquo and toString doing the same for the first thing I want to do (filter --> option 1 and 2 gives the same result) but not for the second thing I wanna do (sum --> option 1 works but option 2 gives me an error). Is it just because I use it within a dplyr pipe?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)


### define dataframe
dataframe_test <- data.frame(
  column_test = c(100,99,99,90,89,50),
  month_test = c("2020-09-01", "2020-09-01","2020-09-01", "2020-09-01","2020-10-01","2020-10-01")
)



test_function <- function(df, df_col_indicator, df_col_month, char_month) {
  
  
  ### define variables for enquo, ensym, toString
  df_col_indicator_enquo <- enquo(df_col_indicator)
  df_col_indicator_ensym <- ensym(df_col_indicator)
  df_col_indicator_toString <- toString(df_col_indicator)
  
  df_col_month_ensym <- ensym(df_col_month)

  
  dataframe2 <- df %>%
    filter(!!df_col_month_ensym == char_month) %>% # filter for month
    slice_max(!!df_col_indicator_ensym, n = 3) %>% # slice top 3 observations
  
    ## two options for filter
    # option 1
    filter(!!df_col_indicator_ensym == df[2, df_col_indicator_toString]) # filter for observations with same observation as second row
    # option 2
    #filter(!!df_col_indicator_ensym == df[2, !!df_col_indicator_enquo])
  
  
  ## two options for sum
  # option 1
  bb <- sum(dataframe2[ , df_col_indicator_toString]) # sum up observations
  
  # option 2
  #bb <- sum(dataframe2[ , !!df_col_indicator_enquo])
  
  return(bb)
  
}


test_function(df = dataframe_test, df_col_indicator = "column_test", df_col_month = "month_test" , char_month = "2020-09-01")
```

**EDIT:**

Thank you all for your answers. Hehe, ok I have to admitt that the example is a bit stupid, but I tried to keep it as simple as possible here. My initial problem is actually this one (see below). I basically try to select top 5 numbers of a column. There are three different outcomes. 1) If more than 5 are  ==100, then I wanna randomly store 5 oberservation in list(indicator) the other observations in list(asterisk). 2) If not all observations are ==100 but there are ties (5th, 6th place have the same value), I wanna randomly pick those with ties and again put some in list(indicator)the other observations in list(asterisk). 3) If thre are no ties, just pick top 5 observations. My main problem now is if I want to run my function over a loop (with all the columns) at the very bottom. Somehow I always just get the first row as an outcome... I think I somehow don't understand how to propperly set variable names for the function within a loop...?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)

remove(list = ls())


dataframe_test <- data.frame(
  county_name = c("a", "b","c", "d","e", "f", "g", "h"),
  column_test1 = c(100,100,100,100,100,100,50,50),
  column_test2 = c(40,90,50,40,40,100,13,14),
  column_test3 = c(100,90,50,40,30,40,100,50),
  month = c("2020-09-01", "2020-09-01" ,"2020-09-01" ,"2020-09-01" ,"2020-09-01" ,"2020-09-01" ,"2020-08-01","2020-08-01"))


choose_top_5 <- function(df, df_col_indicator, df_col_month, char_month, numb_top, df_col_county) {

  ### enquo / ensym / deparse
  df_col_indicator_enquo <- enquo(df_col_indicator)
  df_col_indicator_ensym <- ensym(df_col_indicator)

  df_col_month_ensym <- ensym(df_col_month)
  df_col_month_enquo = enquo(df_col_month)


  ### filter month and top 5 observations
  df_top <- df %>%
    filter(!!df_col_month_ensym == char_month) %>%
    slice_max(!!df_col_indicator_ensym, n = numb_top) %>%
    select(!!df_col_county, !!df_col_month_ensym, !!df_col_indicator_ensym)


  ### if there are more than "numb_top" values and all equals to 100 --> randomly pick "numb_top"
  if (nrow(df_top) > numb_top &
      sum(df_top[ , df_col_indicator  ]) == 100*nrow(df_top)  ) {

    ## randomly pick "numb_top" out of all
    random_shuffle <- df_top[sample(nrow(df_top)),]
    indicator <- random_shuffle[1:numb_top,]
    asterisk <- random_shuffle[(numb_top+1):nrow(random_shuffle),]

    ## return "numb_top" and put names of others in asterisk
    return_list <- list(indicator, asterisk)


    ### if there are more than "numb_top" values but not all 100 (e.g. 100, 100, 100, 99, 99, 99)
    ## --> pick randomly 99 values
  } else if (nrow(df_top) > numb_top) {

    ### filter for all observations that have the same value as "numb_top"
    df_treshold <- df_top %>%
      filter(!!df_col_indicator_ensym == df_top[numb_top, df_col_indicator])

    ## randomly shuffle the observations
    random_shuffle <- df_treshold[sample(nrow(df_treshold)),]

    ## combine observations again an pick "numb_top"
    combine <- rbind(df_top[1:(nrow(df_top)-nrow(df_treshold)), ], random_shuffle)
    indicator <- combine[1:numb_top,]
    asterisk <- combine[(numb_top+1):nrow(combine),]

    ## return "numb_top" and put names of others in asterisk
    return_list <- list(indicator, asterisk)

    ### if there are not more than "numb_top" values
  } else {


    indicator <- df_top
    asterisk <- NA

    ## return "numb_top", asterisk is NA
    return_list <- list(indicator, asterisk)
  }

  return(return_list)


}



### function for 1 column
a=choose_top_5(df = dataframe_test, df_col_indicator = "column_test3",
             df_col_month = "month", char_month = "2020-09-01", numb_top = 5,
             df_col_county = "county_name")
a



### function over all columns and store in list

all_indicators <- c("column_test1","column_test2","column_test3")

my_list <- list()

for (i in all_indicators) {

  my_list[[i]] <- choose_top_5(df = dataframe_test, df_col_indicator = i,
                                        df_col_month = "month", char_month = "2020-09-01", numb_top = 5,
                                        df_col_county = "county_name")
}

my_list
```

Answer (score 3):

To add to Allans answer above:

Normally, you cannot use the forcing operator `!!` inside functions that do not support *quasiquotation*. However, as Lionel Henry pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64452369/r-how-to-pass-a-function-as-a-string-inside-another-function/64458500#64458500) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64594973/use-quasiquotation-for-formula-syntax-in-a-user-created-function/64597068#64597068) an upcoming version of {rlang} is likely to contain a function called `blast()` for *quasiquotation* with immediate evaluation. Below I use your example. In the last row you can see how `!!` can be used inside base R functions which themselves do not support *quasiquoation*.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)

### define dataframe
dataframe_test <- data.frame(
  column_test = c(100,99,99,90,89,50),
  month_test = c("2020-09-01", "2020-09-01","2020-09-01", "2020-09-01","2020-10-01","2020-10-01")
)

blast <- function(expr, env = caller_env()) {
  eval_bare(enexpr(expr), env)
}

test_function <- function(df, df_col_indicator, df_col_month, char_month) {
  
  df_col_indicator_enquo <- enquo(df_col_indicator)
  df_col_indicator_ensym <- ensym(df_col_indicator)
  df_col_month_enquo     <- enquo(df_col_month)
  
  temp <- df %>%
    filter(!!df_col_month_enquo == char_month) %>% 
    slice_max(!!df_col_indicator_enquo, n = 3) %>% 
    filter(!!df_col_indicator_enquo == df %>% 
             select(!!df_col_indicator_enquo) %>% 
             pluck(1, 2)) 
  
  # with `blast()` we can use the forcing operator !! inside sum(`$`...)
  blast(sum(`$`(temp, !! df_col_indicator_ensym)))
}

test_function(df = dataframe_test, column_test, month_test , "2020-09-01")
#> [1] 198
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

It's worth pointing out that `toString` isn't really doing anything here. If you pass a character to `toString` with no other arguments, it remains unchanged:

```
test_toString <- function(x) identical(x, toString(x))

test_toString("hello")
#> [1] TRUE
```

So `df_col_indicator_toString` could be taken out of your function and replaced with `df_col_indicator`.

It's also worth pointing out that when you `enquo` a variable that is a string, then unquote it with the double bang (`!!`) operator, you are left with the original string, so there is no point using `enquo` in your function if you are passing a string.

That means that we can simplify your function by doing:

```r
test_function <- function(df, df_col_indicator, df_col_month, char_month) {

  df_col_indicator_ensym <- ensym(df_col_indicator)
  df_col_month_ensym     <- ensym(df_col_month)

  dataframe2 <- df %>%
    filter(!!df_col_month_ensym == char_month) %>% 
    slice_max(!!df_col_indicator_ensym, n = 3) %>% 
    filter(!!df_col_indicator_ensym == df[2, df_col_indicator]) 

  sum(dataframe2[ , df_col_indicator])
}

test_function(df = dataframe_test, "column_test", "month_test" , "2020-09-01")
#> [1] 198
```

The use of `enquo` and double-bang (together known as quasiquotation) inside user-defined functions is more commonly used to be able to pass columns without needing quotation marks around column names. For example, if your change your function to:

```r
test_function <- function(df, df_col_indicator, df_col_month, char_month) {

  df_col_indicator_enquo <- enquo(df_col_indicator)
  df_col_month_enquo     <- enquo(df_col_month)

  df %>%
    filter(!!df_col_month_enquo == char_month) %>% 
    slice_max(!!df_col_indicator_enquo, n = 3) %>% 
    filter(!!df_col_indicator_enquo == df %>% 
                                        select(!!df_col_indicator_enquo) %>% 
                                        pluck(1, 2)) %>% 
    summarize(total = sum(!!df_col_indicator_enquo)) %>%
    pluck(1, 1)
}
```

Then you can do:

```r
test_function(df = dataframe_test, column_test, month_test , "2020-09-01")
#> [1] 198
```

To answer your broader question about why you are getting the error, then the answer is that you can only use this syntax inside a *quasiquotation context*. Don't confuse this with the pipe; there are certain tidyverse functions where you can use quasiquotation, but in base R functions you can't, which is why method 2 doesn't work. Essentially, the function in which you use the `!!` operator has to be written specifically to handle quasiquotation; base R isn't written that way.

As a final point, your function logic seems a bit unusual, and you should check that this is really what you are trying to do. You are filtering the month, selecting the top three entries, but then filtering *that* according to whether the top three entries are equal to the value in the second row of your *original* data frame, before summing. This seems like a strange thing to want to do.

Comment: thank you a lot. yeah I know, weird example, but this was just an example to try to find out the answer for my initial problem. I edited my actual problem now above..